# uwsgi+flask to start|stop a python daemon process

Tags: python, flask, uwsgi, python-daemon

I have an app writen by python with Flask, and  deploy it use uwsgi +ngix, here is my config of uwsgi:

```
[uwsgi]
master=true
socket = :8223
chdir= /SWS/swdzweb
wsgi-file = manage.py
callable = app
processes = 4
threads = 2
```

My app will response a request which want to start or stop a daemon process writen by pytho too.  as below

in the request function do

```
os.system("python /SWS/webservice.py %s" % cmd)
```

where cmd is start|stop. in my daemon process, it is single process and single thread, and  i capture SIGTEM then exit,like this

```
signal(SIGTERM, lambda signo,handler:sys.exit(0))
```

But. when I start this daemon process by uwsgi in my request function, i can't stop it,  for example

```
kill -15 pid or python /SWS/web service.py stop
```

just like the SIGTERM signal  does not send to my daemon process.

however, when i config uwsgi with 4 processes and 1 thread,  this works fine. config like this

```
[uwsgi]
master=true
socket = :8223
chdir= /SWS/swdzweb
wsgi-file = manage.py
callable = app
processes = 4
threads = 1
```

I can not figure out the reason, so I have to ask for  help.

Thanks!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!